# What is the correct way to query a table AND XML column in the same query in SQL Server 2008 and above?

Tags: xml, t-sql

I'm trying to query a table and the contents of one of the table's XML columns from the same query.

My table schema which is essentially the following:

```
CREATE TABLE AuditLogs
(
    [AuditLogId] INT, 
    [ObjectType] VARCHAR(50), 
    [Action] VARCHAR(50), 
    [ObjectId] INT, 
    [Changes] XML
);
```

With XML in the `Changes` column similar to:

```
<ArrayOfChange>
    <Change FieldName="ItemStatus">
        <OldValue>Unreconciled</OldValue>
        <NewValue>Reconciled</NewValue>
    </Change>
    <Change FieldName="Amount">
        <OldValue>50.00</OldValue>
        <NewValue>45.00</NewValue>
    </Change>
</ArrayOfChange>
```

Finally, the results I'm hankering for are:

```
AuditLogId
Action
ObjectType
ObjectId
FieldName
OldValue
NewValue
```

In true StackOverflow tradition, I've had some attempts at this myself, made some progress and I think I'm almost there, just missing something. The problem I'm having is the OldValue and NewValue columns are always null.

My latest version is:

```
SELECT
    [AuditLogId],
    [Action],
    [ObjectType],
    [ObjectId],
    c.n.value('@FieldName', 'varchar(50)') AS FieldName,
    c.n.value('(OldValue)[0]', 'varchar(50)') AS OldValue,
    c.n.value('(NewValue)[0]', 'varchar(50)') AS NewValue
FROM TMP
    CROSS APPLY [Changes].nodes('/ArrayOfChange/Change') c(n)
```

Now, I've  created an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e044c/) to make life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath is letting you down.

Change

```
c.n.value('(OldValue)[0]', 'varchar(50)') AS OldValue,
c.n.value('(NewValue)[0]', 'varchar(50)') AS NewValue
```

to

```
c.n.value('OldValue[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS OldValue,
c.n.value('NewValue[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS NewValue
```

Xpath is 1-based (lots of thoughts on the subject [in this blogpost](http://mukulgandhi.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/blog-post.html)); and you don't need those parentheses with such a simple path expression (they're allowed, but unnecessary here).